# I cannot create NSImage with imageNamed but initWithContentsOfFile

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsimage, nsbundle

With the following code:

```
NSString *imageString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"logo64x64" ofType:@"png"];
NSImage *testImage = [[NSImage imageNamed:@"logo64X64"] retain];
NSImage *testImage2 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageString];
```

`testImage` is nil but `testImage2` is a `NSImage` instance. I don't know what's wrong with the code. I'm sure I can find `logo64x64.png` and `logo64x64@2x.png` in the resource directory in the bundle. I've also tried `imageNamed:@"logo64X64.png"` but still getting nil.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
[NSImage imageNamed:@"logo64x64"];
```

rather than

```
[NSImage imageNamed:@"logo64X64"];
```

Note that in the code that succeeded, you used a lowercase `x`, whereas in the code that failed, you used an uppercase `X` (`logo64X64`). `NSBundle` is case-sensitive, even if the underlying HFS+ file system is only case-preserving. (`NSImage`'s `+imageNamed:` method uses `NSBundle` to locate resources).

Comment: Thanks so much. Shame on my carelessness. Then it seems to be `not a real question` :) Haha

Comment: Nice observation. I didn't get it in first look.